# How to create multiple communities in jomsocial?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, jomsocial

My client want a multiple profile website.

It has **multiple management companies** and each company have to create **multiple communities** and each community will have **separate admin** to manage the users events and profiles inside the community. I am using jomsocial for the community purpose, but i don't know how to add multiple communities in a particular profile type(Means Management company) and add each community to a new admin.

If any one already has the experience means please share it.
Thanks.

Comment: contact the developers of JomSocial then. It´s their extension and they provide support for it

Comment: I have tried to contact them. But still am not getting any response from them. Reference : http://www.jomsocial.com/forum/pre-sales-questions/12491-is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-communities-profiles-using-jomsocial#63297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it myself,

First i have created new joomla groups - management company and users.

After that I have  given access to the management company to create new jomsocial gorups(Community), and giving permission to one of the user to a group admin.

Jomsocial has the default function for edit and delete events and group activities only into the group admin.

So now the website has three users, one for super admin, and another for management company, they can just create new community and manage the users and final one for website users can manage the activities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to change JomSocial into a multi community app because it all runs together at some point. Images, Events etc.

What you could try is using JoomlaXi's Profile Types.

http://www.joomlaxi.com/jomsocial-profile-type.html

You can have different fields when users register to this type and manage access with it and much more.